# Wrapping text written on a image

Tags: php, image, gd, php-gd

I want to write a wrapped text to a image with php. Here is a [demo](http://cruisear.com/demo/3). If you copy, paste and send text below to [demo](http://cruisear.com/demo/3) you will notice that some lines are distorted and there is some paragraph spaces which must not be there. I am looking to the code for hours. I couldn't understand where is the problem. Is there anybody help me?

Sample Text:

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ut justo
>   consectetur, cursus lorem vitae, accumsan lorem. Cras eu odio
>   vulputate, rhoncus dui vel, aliquam lorem. Fusce scelerisque facilisis
>   lacus, quis malesuada justo placerat nec. Curabitur elementum mattis
>   nisl, sed sodales mauris congue et. Nunc velit mauris, accumsan a
>   dictum vitae, pellentesque luctus leo. Maecenas in venenatis orci.
>   Suspendisse sed neque magna. Praesent vitae sapien porttitor diam
>   aliquam eleifend. Maecenas lacinia elit non velit vehicula rutrum. Sed
>   ultricies mauris vitae dapibus tempor. Praesent eros metus, euismod ut
>   est eget, rhoncus iaculis lorem. Ut aliquet dictum ligula lobortis
>   cursus. Sed mattis ante ut odio tincidunt venenatis. Donec euismod
>   quam sit amet velit tincidunt, ut convallis ligula tempor. Quisque
>   tincidunt elit sem, quis laoreet orci accumsan in.

```
$mx = imagesx($im);   // Width of the created image
$my = imagesy($im);   // Height of the image

//TEXT VARS/////////
$main_text = $text;   // $text variable comes directly from the form
$main_text_size = 20; // $text font size

$words = explode(' ', $main_text);
$lines = array($words[0]);
$currentLine = 0;

    for($i = 1; $i < count($words); $i++)
    {
        $lineSize = imagettfbbox($main_text_size, 0, $font, $lines[$currentLine] . ' ' . $words[$i]);
        if($lineSize[2] - $lineSize[0] < ($mx-20))
        {
            $lines[$currentLine] .= ' ' . $words[$i];
        }
        else
        {
            $currentLine++;
            $lines[$currentLine] = $words[$i];
        }
    } 

$line_count = 1;
// Loop through the lines and place them on the image
foreach ($lines as $line)
{
    $line_box = imagettfbbox($main_text_size, 0, $font, "$line");
    $line_height = $line_box[1]-$line_box[7];
    $line_y = (($line_height+4) * $line_count);
    imagettftext($im, $main_text_size, 0, 5, $line_y, $black, $font, $line);

    // Increment Y so the next line is below the previous line
    $line_count ++;
}   

imagepng($im, 'image.png');
imagedestroy($im);
```

Comment: Have you included all the relevant code because I'm getting quite a few errors when just trying to set up a test site?

Comment: @MartinMetsalu First of all, You have to define the  `$im`  an set it a background color and define `$black`, `$yellow`, `$font` variables. I didn't put these parts here.

Comment: Why are you doing this? "$words = explode(' ', $main_text);
$lines = array($words[0]);". $words[0] will be the first word of $main_text.